# why am I getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" error in my project

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts2

I have no idea why this error is coming in my project.so you guys are my last chance:

In my project I am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" Exception.Can you tell   me    what is the reason behind it.

```
when I am trying to run this program I am getting this message"
  HTTP status 404
INSIDE the console I am getting this error
```

t would be REALLY appreciated if you could give me some hints...

Thanks a lot,

```
  SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4537)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
 SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class    com.olec.listener.HibernateListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.olec.listener.HibernateListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4537)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5097)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5092)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
 SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
  Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/OLEC] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader    clearReferencesJdbc
    SEVERE: The web application [/OLEC] registered the JDBC driver                                                                                                                                                 [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]    but failed to unregister it when the web application   was             stopped. To prevent a                                                          memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been  unregistered.
Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 24, 2012 4:47:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2014 ms
```

Comment: if you are using tiles and struts2, you should add `struts2-tiles-plugin` to your classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IDE are you using? In case of Eclipse or Netbeans got to the project properties and add 
missing jar into the class path.

According to your exception you should add struts2-tiles-plugin-2.0.12.jar or any other version of that jar.

Also hibernate-annotations.jar , better check if your class path is correct all together.

Answer (score 0):

com.olec.listener.HibernateListener is missing. I have found no jar containing that class, but you should add it to your app or its classpath.